# what does -f and -p option to Java command

Tags: java

I have a script file which executes the java program like:
`java -Dlog.file=/path -Dappname=name -DAsyncLogger.RingBufferSize=200000 -jar /path/main.jar   -f /path/testfile -day 20211108 -p /path/test.properties`

`-D` I understand puts the key-value pair into system properties,
I am unsure what these other `-f`, `-day`, `-p` do.

**Code:**

```java
public class Mainprogram extends PPS{
    @Parameter(names={"-f", "-fileToRep1ay'}, description = "sample", required=true)
    protected static String fileToReplay;
    public MainProgram(Logger logger) { super(logger);}
    public static void main(string[] args) throws Exception {
        new MainProgram(LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainProgram.class))
            .withArgs(args)
            .start(new DispatcherModuIe() ,
                new SessionManagerModuIe() ,
                new FixHarnessModUIe(fiLeToReplay,
                    currentBusinessDay)) ;
```

Comment: These are options for the main.jar file. They could mean anything, and depend only on what the main.jar is supposed to do.

Comment: Everything after the `-jar /path/main.jar` option is an option to the application and is ignored by the JVM. You're looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `java`, all options after the class name or `-jar <jarfile>` are passed as-is to the `public static void main(String[] args)` method. In this case, the main method of this JAR will receive the array `{"-f", "/path/testfile", "-day", "20211108", "-p", "/path/test.properties"}`.

What they mean and how they are interpreted is application specific, so your question cannot be answered in general.

That said, based on the context, I **guess** `-f` specifies a file (possibly input, possibly output), `-day` specifies a date in ISO-8601 format without dashes, and `-p` specifies a properties file (e.g. configuration or something like that).

And as mentioned in the comments by [g00se](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16376827/g00se), most professionally developed applications will provide an explanation of the options by running it with `-h` and/or `--help`.

Comment: If your app is professionally written, it will be worth doing `java -jar /path/main.jar -h` or `java -jar /path/main.jar --help` to find out what those options are for

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I also updated the code. It makes sense now. In the code, it uses @Parameter annotation. Does that directly initializes the variables?

Comment: @g00se -h didn't return anything. But I checked the code. I do see `description` written for each of these arguments

Comment: OK, that's good. So now *you* can 'professionalize' it so that the next person who has that problem can find out - it could be you;)

Comment: @dnaiel If this is your own application, why did you even ask this question? You should know what your application does. In any case, `@Parameter` is not a standard Java annotation, so this is probably specific to the CLI parsing library this application is using.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I don't own this application. I am a new joiner in a project, and I was trying to get it run with the jar file. I was getting some issues, and then I downloaded the source code. But I cannot run the source code that seems to be having some other problems, so someone suggested working with the jar directly, for now, to speed up the process.

Comment: @dnaiel I suggest that you ask your colleagues instead of random strangers on the internet.

Comment: I think you meant “ISO 8601 format,” not ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Actually, I am a new joiner, and I am not sure about running this program I am not seeing any output when I run the jar file, on the other hand, the code I have has a compilation error. This seems to be a weird situation to me. As the tech lead seems to be busy with his work and there is no one to assist me. I doubt if I could figure out why the jar file is not producing any output unless the original java code is understood

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Schokokuchen Bäcker, the options could mean anything. If it helps though, from your description, I would say:

`-f` - *path to test file*

`-day` - *date* (ISO-8859-1 format sans dashes)

`-p` - *path to properties file*